# Difference between super and this while calling a function in sub class in js

Tags: javascript

```js
class A {
  data1 = 1;
  constructor(){
    this.data2 = 2;
  }
  test() { console.log(this) }
}
class B extends A {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  funcA() { this.test() }
  funcB() { super.test() }
}
let foo = new B()
foo.funcA();
foo.funcB();
```

what's the difference between `funcA()` and `funcB()` while calling, or they are exactly the same thing?
BTW, what's the difference between `data1` and `data2` declared in and out the constructor, which is preferred

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `this.test()`, you reference the *instance*. No `test` property exists directly on the instance, so as with standard prototypal inheritance, the prototype object is examined for the property. This prototype is `A.prototype`, which does have a `test` property, so that gets called.

With `super.test()`, you instead start looking for the `test` property on the superclass - `A.prototype`, which is found immediately and called.

If you had a `test` method on B as well, you'd see the difference.

```js
class A {
  data1 = 1;
  constructor(){
    this.data2 = 2;
  }
  test() { console.log('a') }
}
class B extends A {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  test() {
    console.log('b');
  }
  funcA() { this.test() }
  funcB() { super.test() }
}
const foo = new B()
foo.funcA();
foo.funcB();
```

> BTW, what's the difference between data1 and data2 declared in and out the constructor, which is preferred

It's up to you. Though, class fields (assigning outside of the constructor) are slightly more concise (especially if your constructor doesn't contain anything else) but less supported - if you want to use them, make sure to transpile your code.